# Function from Page1 used in Page2

Tags: c#, frame, navigationservice

I have a window with a frame.

Said frame can get 2 different pages: Page1 and Page2.

Page1 has combobox1 and a button1.

Page2 has combobox2 and a button2.

Note: combobox1 and combobox2 are populated with same data.

When in Page1, clicking button1 takes us to Page2 (at this pointcombobox1 is not relevant.)

On Page2 we should set a value in combobox2. By clicking button2 we should go to Page1 and get combobox1 updated with the same value as combobox2.

I was able to go back to Page1 with:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

But I can't seem to find a way to update my combobox1 in any way.

I tried handlers but I wasn't able to make it work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you just databind the two comboboxes to the same source?

Comment: I probably can, but honestly i am not sure how to do that :(

Programming is like a hobby to me and although i am learning a lot with this small app i am creating, this databind thing is something i am not familiar with yet

Comment: Assuming this is WPF you're using, I'd strongly recommend having a look through a website like this: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/
There's a section on there about data binding, but it's probably worth going through the earlier pages first.

Comment: It is indeed WPF, will take a look, thanks

Comment: I was able to understand what the binding means but i dont get how i can use it to solve my problem, because i am working with different classes here Class Page1 and Class Page2, so one is independent from the other although i want to use some stuff mutually

Comment: Then you need to create a class containing shared data. If both pages have a reference to one instance of that class, changing the value of properties on that object from Page1 will update Page2 as well, and vice versa.

Comment: I dont see to get how to do that. I get a class in page 1 that is public partial class Page1 : Page and then in page 2 i have public partial class Page2 : Page. After this i cant create a class that gets both Page1 and Page2